# sbt on linux not accepting -jvm-debug 5005

Tags: linux, debugging, intellij-idea, sbt, archlinux

I'm using sbt launcher version 0.13.7 on Arch Linux from the official arch repositories. I'm trying to debug a scala app using IntelliJ.

Everywhere else I looked, including other stack overflow questions, seemed to say that Linux versions of sbt can be debugged by simply invoking "sbt -jvm-debug 5005"

However, when I do this, I get a long string of errors:

```
[warn] The `-` command is deprecated in favor of `onFailure` and will be removed in 0.14.0
[error] Expected letter
[error] Expected symbol
[error] Expected '!'
[error] Expected '+'
[error] Expected '++'
[error] Expected 'debug'
[error] Expected 'info'
[error] Expected 'warn'
[error] Expected 'error'
[error] Expected ';'
[error] Expected end of input.
[error] Expected '--'
[error] Expected 'show'
[error] Expected 'all'
[error] Expected '*'
[error] Expected '{'
[error] Expected project ID
[error] Expected configuration
[error] Expected key
[error] Expected '-'
[error] 5005
[error] ^
[error] Not a valid command: jvm-debug
[error] Not a valid project ID: jvm-debug
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: jvm-debug
[error] jvm-debug
[error]          ^
```

Why is this, and how can I set an sbt project to debug on a port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It appears that this works:

```
export SBT_OPTS="-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005" && sbt
```

However, I would still like to know why "sbt -jvm-debug 5005" isn't working on Arch if anyone knows.

Comment: I'm under Windows 10 and I have the exact same error. I was using the activator and moved to sbt since it EOL-ed at the end of the year. Very weird...

Comment: also happening on macOS X when running sbt -jvm-debug 5005

Answer (score 1):

*The question is about SBT on Linux, but I ran into the same issue in OS X.*

SBT 0.13.9 in OS X neither accepts `-jvm-debug` nor follows `SBT_OPTS` environment as presented in the accepted answer.

However, this works:

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005"
```